# Export a KMeans model using export_savedmodel to deploy on ml-engine

Tags: python-2.7, csv, tensorflow, k-means, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm doing a K-means clustering using tensorflow.contrib.learn.KMeansClustering.

**I can use it default model to predict local but since I want to use ml-engine online prediction, I must export it to a export_savedmodel format.**

I have google lot's of place but since KMeansClustering class needs no feature columns so I don't know how to build the correct serving_input_fn for export_savedmodel

Here is my code

```
# Generate input_fn
def gen_input(data):
    return tf.constant(data.as_matrix(), tf.float32, data.shape), None

# Declare dataset + export model path
TRAIN = 'train.csv'
MODEL = 'model'

# Read dataset
body = pd.read_csv(
    file_io.FileIO(TRAIN, mode='r'),
    delimiter=',',
    header=None,
    engine='python'
)

# Declare K-Means
km = KMeansClustering(
    num_clusters=2,
    model_dir=MODEL,
    relative_tolerance=0.1
)

est = km.fit(input_fn=lambda: gen_input(body))

# This place is where I stuck
fcols = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('x', dimension=5)]
fspec = tf.contrib.layers.create_feature_spec_for_parsing(fcols)
serving_input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.python.learn.\
                   utils.input_fn_utils.build_parsing_serving_input_fn(fspec)
est.export_savedmodel(MODEL, serving_input_fn)
```

Here is my toy train.csv

```
1,2,3,4,5
2,3,4,5,6
3,4,5,6,7
5,4,3,2,1
7,6,5,4,3
8,7,6,5,4
```

Exported model have the format of saved_model.pb with its variables folder

Deploying the model to ml-engine was successful, but when predicting with same train.csv I got the following error

```
{"error": "Prediction failed: Exception during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=\"Name: <unknown>, Feature: x (data type: float) is required but could not be found.\n\t [[Node: ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=1, Nsparse=0, Tdense=[DT_FLOAT], _output_shapes=-1,5, dense_shapes=5, sparse_types=[], _device=\"/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0\"](_arg_input_example_tensor_0_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/names, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, ParseExample/Const)]]\")"}
```

I have struggled with this for month while all documents that I found are for pure API

I'm looking forward to your advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the exact same error I am facing now. It would be more helpful for me if I get the code you have used and deploying the model in cloud ML engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Census sample [shows](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/estimator/trainer/model.py#L197) how to setup the serving_input_fn for CSV. Adjusted for your example:

```
CSV_COLUMNS = ['feat1', 'feat2', 'feat3', 'feat4', 'feat5']
CSV_COLUMN_DEFAULTS = [[0.0],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0]] 

def parse_csv(rows_string_tensor):
  """Takes the string input tensor and returns a dict of rank-2 tensors."""

  # Takes a rank-1 tensor and converts it into rank-2 tensor
  # Example if the data is ['csv,line,1', 'csv,line,2', ..] to
  # [['csv,line,1'], ['csv,line,2']] which after parsing will result in a
  # tuple of tensors: [['csv'], ['csv']], [['line'], ['line']], [[1], [2]]
  row_columns = tf.expand_dims(rows_string_tensor, -1)
  columns = tf.decode_csv(row_columns, record_defaults=CSV_COLUMN_DEFAULTS)
  features = dict(zip(CSV_COLUMNS, columns))

  return features

def csv_serving_input_fn():
  """Build the serving inputs."""
  csv_row = tf.placeholder(
      shape=[None],
      dtype=tf.string
  )
  features = parse_csv(csv_row)
  return tf.contrib.learn.InputFnOps(features, None, {'csv_row': csv_row})

# No need for fcols/fspec
est.export_savedmodel(MODEL, serving_input_fn)
```

TensorFlow 1.4 will simplify at least some of this.

Also, consider using JSON, as that is the more standard approach for serving. Happy to provide details upon request.

Comment: How do we use KMeans Saved Tensor Flow Model to make predictions,  uploading the model in google storage bucket and do some predictions via CloudML serving the model from Storage Bucket? Can you help me with this? I am uploading the gist code here for your reference. https://gist.github.com/Madhivarman/e9e0ab7f5ef03b7f93ffbd62f6afb848

Comment: Did you try the approach of the OP?

Comment: sorry I couldn't understand..! OP?

Comment: original poster: this thread has some sample code that appears to be usable, but which is a little different from yours, so I'm wondering if you can adopt the approach in this thread

Comment: Yeah, I will try to do that. If anything doesn't work out I will refactor the code according to this code. Thanks!